# name 'raw' is not defined in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

Python 2.7
Scapy (2.3.3)

I tried to run a scapy demo

```
server@root:/usr/bin$ sudo ./scapy
INFO: Can't import matplotlib. Won't be able to plot.
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Welcome to Scapy (2.3.3)
```

ran following command
`>>> raw(IP())`

get error message like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'raw' is not defined
```

I am beginner in python.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw()` is new in Scapy 2.4.0 (including release candidates, aka 2.4.0-rc*).

You can either install Scapy 2.4.0 or newer, or use `str()` for now.